# Android adding item to list preference programaticly

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, listpreference

I feel like i have been searching every where without finding an answer to this.

I have a list preference

```
     <ListPreference
            android:key="signedUpCompetetion"
            android:entries="@array/listArray"
             android:entryValues="@array/listValues"
                />
```

With the following entries and entryValues:

```
    <resources>
<string-array name="listArray">
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="listValues">
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

So say that in one of my activities i want to add something to the list.

The following is an attempt but it doesnt seem to work:

```
this.appPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
this.prefEditor = appPrefs.edit();
ListPreference list = (ListPreference) getSharedPreferences("signedUpCompetetion", MODE_PRIVATE);
list.setEntries("This is a test");
```

Anyone able to tell me how to add to a listpreference?

**Update**
By the looks of it this seems to work

```
        PreferenceScreen root = this.getPreferenceScreen();
    ListPreference list = (ListPreference) root.findPreference("signedUpCompetetion");
    CharSequence[] entries = { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    CharSequence[] entryValues = { "1", "2", "3" };
    list.setEntries(entries);
    list.setEntryValues(entryValues);
```

However there is 1 problem! if i restart the application the list is not preserved. which means that the list is empty!

Comment: Now after the update, it is not clear what exactly is the problem. Do you mean the list appears on the first launch but does not on consecutive launches? How are you managing your activity lifecycle?

Comment: Does the list appear automatically on the first launch? Or you expect a user interaction (for example, a button press)?

Comment: Okay let me and explain exactly what i mean: I want to have list where i can add Strings doing runtime the catch with this list is that it must be presvered when the application closes so that next time the user opens the application he will be able to see the full list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setEntries(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#setEntries%28int%29) and [`setEntryValues(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#setEntryValues%28int%29)

```
    list.setEntries(R.array.listArray);
    list.setEntryValues(R.array.listValues);
```

**Update for how to persist the data:**

You can persist the data in [several ways](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), the simplest one would be to call [`setPersistent(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setPersistent%28boolean%29):

```
    list.setPersistent(true);
```

Comment: This does seem to work however if i reload the application the list is not saved?

Comment: What do you mean by _reload the application?_

Comment: Usually when you have an edittextpreference you can close the application and open it again the preference remain however if i add text programaticly the list is empty when i restart the application

Comment: With this how would you add a single value to the list?

Comment: how do you retrieve the list to setEntries?

Comment: @eri0o, please post a new question.

Comment: @MarcRasmussen, sorry for a late response :) 
If you are adding the preferences programmatically, you need to set the default values (or previously set values, by reading  them from shared prefs) on the start.