# How to dynamically show google accounts in preferencelist?

Tags: android

I am developing preference Settings screen and i want to make a list of google accounts of device, 
which displays dialog on click of list preference.


Here, i want to bind accounts dynamically to list preference.
Is it possible to make this type of preference screen ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getUsername(){
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this); 
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google"); 
    List<String> possibleEmails = new LinkedList<String>();

    for (Account account : accounts) {
      // TODO: Check possibleEmail against an email regex or treat
      // account.name as an email address only for certain account.type values.
      possibleEmails.add(account.name);
    }

    if(!possibleEmails.isEmpty() && possibleEmails.get(0) != null){
        String email = possibleEmails.get(0);
        String[] parts = email.split("@");
        if(parts.length > 0 && parts[0] != null)
            return parts[0];
        else
            return null;
    }else
        return null;
}
```

by using AccountManager feature.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: thank you for reply...above code gives me accounts then how can i bind them with my preferencelist ?

Comment: you can convert them to strings then use this way to add them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16754542/1932105 .. please accept and upvote if helped.